# branes-collision -> big-bang -> 2nd Universe?

Tags: string-theory, big-bang, branes

If the  cosmological model of the [Ekpyrotic universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe) is correct should there not
always a 2nd universe be created on the 2nd brane?

Pictures and articles I found speak only of one universe.

[image: branes-collision]

Why is that? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on the subject, but according to one of the proponents of this model (http://wwwphy.princeton.edu/~steinh/npr/), the 2 branes "stick" to create the universe. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense.